# Follow up question marked as duplicate of my previous question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

I asked this [question about sorting in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299925/mongoose-sort-by-nested-field?noredirect=1#comment87624805_50299925). I found out that my issue lay in another place, as the function itself didn't work for me at all. I then [asked why the function itself doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304135/mongoose-sort-not-working-at-all?noredirect=1#comment87624851_50304135).

Then a moderator came into the picture, deemed my second question a duplicate of my first and commented that I should not repost the question. I don't find these questions related to each other. He proceeded to downvote both questions.

I just find this really unnecessary but as I don't have a very long experience with Stack Overflow I would like to know whether I'm wrong in this or his action was incorrect.

Comment: Why did you accept a solution that didn't work for you? Why not simply comment on the answer that it isn't working? You don't know he downvoted anything, voting is not public information.

Comment: @RobertLongson I accepted it because it was helpful, and I know it would work after checking the document he linked. I felt like I was done with that question and the question could not provide me any more help unless I would've edit it a lot to make it relevant to my new-found issue.

Comment: But your new question contains exactly the same markup as your old question doesn't it?

Comment: @RobertLongson Moreover is the revision history in the previous question shows exactly the same question. As the person who put the hold on both questions I've given my reply.

Comment: @NeilLunn That was because I accidentally edited the old question instead making a new question. I had to reroll it back, also his answer wouldn't be still relevant to the question if I didn't re-roll it back to original. It wouldn't be a proper move to edit the whole question, wouldn't it?

Comment: *Then the moderator* I know this is not obvious and different from other sites across the wider internet but on SO we make a distinction between users with moderation privileges and elected moderators.  The latter are recognized by a diamond next to their name. Your question was handled by the former and are not referred to as *moderators*

Comment: @rene I see, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 6):

So I closed the question and then subsequently place a hold on the original question, and I closed them because they are the same question. More to the point let's talk about some facts here:

1. The original question was asked and was given a response. This response identified a clear mistake in your question and corrected it with what I can verify is a correct method for specifying the field to sort.
2. You posted a new question after actually making revisions to the original question and commenting to the person who answered the question. The new question is exactly the same as the revision content which was added to the original before it was revised again.
3. I put a duplicate close on the post and left a comment referring you to the other existing question you had asked.
4. Whist still having your original question open in the browser, I watched as the answer was accepted then unaccepted and so on until you eventually settled on accept and then...
5. This is where you preceded to comment that the question was in fact "not a duplicate". I stated at this point that it clearly was

There is a very simple case here that if you did not believe the previous answer was the solution to what you were asking, then you simply do not accept. Under no circumstance can you decide you "don't like the answer" you received and decide to simply post the question again. This makes it a "self duplicate" and is therefore a straightforward close.

You were in fact given the opportunity to clarify exactly why you thought the solution given does not solve your problem. Yet instead of responding to my very reasonable request, you choose to come and air grievance here.

As it stands, the "original" question I have also placed on hold, since if the "accepted" solution is not actually what you are asking for as an answer, then I can only gauge what you are looking for is either:

- Sorting the actual array inside the document
- Sorting on a specific array entry from inside the document

For which the only possible case is to mark as duplicates for either of those existing solutions.

The whole thing really comes down to "one" of those is certainly your solution, so before you even think of asking again or asking for another question to be reopened, then you really need to consider actually looking at the existing solutions and providing some actual reasonable feedback as to what exactly you expect to happen as a solution to the question you ask.

Answer (score -14):

Since my comments are being deleted, I'm posting my response to Neil Lunn here:

Thanks your response. `1)` totally agree with it. `2)` As I stated earlier, I accidentally had to re-roll the question to original state so the question would be the same. Or else it would ask completely different and make the answer irrelevant.  `3)` No argue there. `4)` No idea what you're talking about there. `5)` Disagree.  -

> There is a very simple case here that if you did not believe the
>   previous answer was the solution to what you were asking, then you
>   simply do not accept. Under no circumstance can you decide you "don't
>   like the answer" you received and decide to simply post the question
>   again. This makes it a "self duplicate" and is therefore a
>   straightforward close.
>
> You were in fact given the opportunity to clarify exactly why you
>   thought the solution given does not solve your problem. Yet instead of
>   responding to my very reasonable request, you choose to come and air
>   grievance here.

As I stated earlier, I found his answer useful, the accept-mark says(when hovering) that it has either solved my problem, or was the most helpful, as I understood how to resolve that question correctly. I was never given the opportunity to clarify excatly what I thought the the soution given does not solve my problem. Also why is my [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299925/mongoose-sort-by-nested-field?noredirect=1#comment87624805_50299925) to your comments gone in the first question? Suppose to be total 4 comments.

> As it stands, the "original" question I have also placed on hold,
>   since if the "accepted" solution is not actually what you are asking
>   for as an answer, then I can only gauge what you are looking for is
>   either:
>
> - Sorting the actual array inside the document
> - Sorting on a specific array entry from inside the document

I see now what the issue is. You cleary sees it as duplicated because you were simply in haste marking it as duplicate as you didn't read the content well. My second question didn't ask about sorting regarding the array at all. I asked why the `.sort()` function didn't work. The array question was already solved in the previous question.

Comment: Please don't use answers as what comments are supposed to be. If your comment was deleted, there where obvious problems with it as mods don't delete comments for no reason.

Comment: "as I understood how to resolve that question correctly". It seems to answer to your first question didn't help you to resolve your question. The second question is basically: "I tried what the first answer suggested but it didn't work".